# what is the action for getting the extension's display name?

Tags: asterisk, amazon-ami, freepbx

I am using astrisks freePBX AMI and I'm looking for the action to find what is the display name of the extension.

What is the action for getting the extension's display name?

Comment: Take your complete post, put it into google, and find [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513364/how-can-i-get-the-name-associated-with-an-extension-peer-without-having-an-opene).

Comment: it says "command not found"

Comment: did you check out the SO article @Patrik linked to?

Comment: It's not working. I'm not using the actual command line I'm communicating with ami and i need to know the command to find the extension's display name and what to put in it. If you could just tell it would be great because the one in the article is not working or I just don't understand what he meant...

Answer (score 0):

You can get display name in freepbx database in table sip.